# Applying css n-th child to angular generated html

Tags: html, css, angularjs

Trying to make sure that the columns are all floated to the left while not having huge gaps between the rows.

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="row hide-for-small">
        <div ng-repeat="module in modules">
            <div class="medium-6 large-4 columns">
                <div class="modBoxContainer">
                    <div class="modBox">
                        <div class="modHeading">
                            <h1><span class="modNumber">{{ module.part }}</span> {{ module.title }}</h1>
                        </div>
                        <ul>
                            <li ng-repeat="section in module.sections">
                                <a ng-href="#/education/{{ module.url }}/{{section.number}}/01"><strong>Part {{ section.number | number:0 }}: </strong>{{ section.title }}</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And as for css it's your average columnar layout through foundation or the like. Columns are fine until they're all different height just as in the picture. I have tried applying n-th child to .modBox and .modBoxContainer but a lot of times it won't even recognize the n-th child rule if used with `:nth-child(n+smth)`...

How could I assign 1 height to the first three columns and different height to the rest of them? I've tried applying `height: auto`, `height: 100%`, combined with `min-height` or just `height` rules specified.

Sorry, can't recreate much of the code in JSFiddle or such as it's a huge project I'm working on, but suggestions would be nice. But some suggestions would be great to try as I'm running dry on ideas.

Here's the screenshot of the problem:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE**: This solution only works for modern browsers (IE9 and up)

For selecting the first three elements, you can do

```
nth-of-type(-n+3)
```

Source

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-of-type.asp

> Using a formula (an + b). Description: a represents a cycle size, n is a counter (starts at 0), and b is an offset value.

Comment: If I do .modBox:nth-of-type(-n+3) it applies it to all .modBox containers regargless as well. Which is my issue in the first place. :(